# Github Actions runners on multiple servers?

Tags: github, nginx, deployment, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have configured a Github Actions runner on my first front-end server, so with every new product-ready push on the main branch the new version is automatically deployed to my server (Ubuntu, Node.js, Nginx & PM2). However I would like to configure a second server that exactly identical server and then load-balance between those two. Therefore I tried to set up a second runner on a second server and I did that "successfully", so the runner is always live, but now every time when I trigger the workflow, Github Actions only deploys to the first that was set up on the first front-end server.

How can I get Github Actions to deploy to both servers? Is this even the right approach or is there another better way to manage that and to set up identical servers/load-balance, and I think Kubernetes can do that, but I am not that deep into Docker yet.

So my question is, if it's possible to do what I described above, and also what maybe what I am doing wrong, and if there is maybe a better solution for this case. Would appreciate any help.

Also here I have my Github Actions workflow

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build
    - run: pm2 restart nextjs
      env:
        CI: true
```

Answer (score 0):

> but now every time when I trigger the workflow, Github Actions only deploys to the first that was set up on the first front-end server.

Every job defined in a Workflow is designed to be delivered from GitHub to the runner only once. This is why your second runner is not receiving the job to execute.

> How can I get Github Actions to deploy to both servers?

In your original approach, the runner that receives the job is responsible for deploying the code to the server it is running on. This means that you do not need to configure a GitHub runner on every server you have.

However, I wouldn't recommend using self-hosted runners on your production servers as it can be risky if the scripts that are triggered by the jobs from GitHub are not written properly. Instead, you can use GitHub runners to build and test your application, and then use another action (e.g. SCP action) to copy the final build to your production servers and run any necessary post-scripts (e.g. restarting the pm2 daemon). This separates the build and deployment processes and can help to prevent potential issues on your production servers.

You can also use a "pull" approach to deploy your application to multiple servers instead. In this approach, you can use the [actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) action to upload the final build files as an artifact and then use another action to notify the production servers to download and extract the artifact, and then run any necessary deployment scripts.